# The current path, api/v1/latest-products, didn't match any of these

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am experiencing this problem following a tutorial and I can't identify the error. Tried changing to re_path and did not work. I created one product in the django admin database already so it should be showing something else instead of the 404 in the address.

"GET /api/v1/latest-products HTTP/1.1" 404 7667
Not Found: /latest-products

Below the code:

URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('latest-products/', 
 views.LatestProductsList.as_view()),
 path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls')),
 path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
 path('api/v1/', include('product.urls')),
 ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
 document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Product
from .serializers import ProductSerializer

class LatestProductsList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
    products = Product.objects.all()[0:4]
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

MODELS.PY

```
class Product(models.Model):
 category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name = 
'products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 slug = models.SlugField()
 description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
 price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, 
 decimal_places=2)
 image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank= 
 True, null = True)
 thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', 
 blank=True, null=True)
 date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show us the contents of `djoser.urls`

Comment: Hi, I can't find that file?.

Answer (score 2):

if it is your root urls.py visit /latest-products/

if it is your app's urls.py, then you need to provide the root urls.py

Assume it is like

```
urlpatterns = [
...
  path('app_label/', include(('app_label.urls', 'app_label'), namespace='app_label'),
...
]
```

then the url should be `/app_label/latest-products/`

Comment: it is in the app urls.py but tried both ways /api/v1/latest-products and /latest-products/ and get the same result.

Comment: @FranciscoAzocar urls are like tree nodes, one `include` will make the inside urls like children nodes. So please provide the root urls to see the detail. And, is there a reason why you put three `urls` into one single path `api/v1/`?

Answer (score 0):

Either change the route you're visiting to `/latest-products/`, either change your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('api/v1/latest-products/', 
 views.LatestProductsList.as_view()),
 # others
```

Comment: Tried it and get the same result. When i check in admins I have the product there.

Comment: Can you add your urls.py from your project folder ?